# AIR custom transparent chrome problem Flash Builder 4.5.1

Tags: air, flash-builder

I'm re-creating an AIR app with FB 4.5.1. (I've started from scratch, having had trouble importing FB 4 projects).

In the app.xml I have the following defined:

```
<systemChrome>none</systemChrome> 
<transparent>true</transparent>
```

Having done this I still get a full window with titlebar, min, max, and close buttons.

what gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I discovered it is easier to interact with app.XML by opening it via "Open With -> Text Editor".

Second, and this is really embarrassing, I had simply failed to remove the comments bracketing

was:

```
    <!-- <systemChrome>none</systemChrome> -->
    <!--<transparent>true</transparent>-->
```

should have been:

```
    <systemChrome>none</systemChrome>
    <transparent>true</transparent>
```

...duh! I knew better, but...

Lastly, for a completely chromeless app, add

```
    showStatusBar="false"
```

to the app header.

that's it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create a skin for the application.

This appears in Adobe's forum, and includes an FXP of a functional transparent app:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/476699

> Setting systemChrome & transparency along with "backgroundAlpha" to "0" would have helped in Flex 3.
>
> But, skinning of components in Flex 4 i.e Spark components is little different and completely customizable.
>
> Following are the steps you need to do make the window transparent.
>
> 1. Set systemChrome to "none" in the XML configuration file
> 2. Set transparent to "true" in the XML configuration file
> 3. Copy the skin code from <SDK_FOLDER>\frameworks\projects\airframework\src\spark\skins\spark\S parkChromeWindowedApplicationSkin.mxml and paste in a new MXML file.
> 4. Set the "alpha" property of "backgroundRect" object inside the skin file to "0".
> 5. Assign the newly created skin as the "skinClass" for "s:WindowedApplication" object
>
> Please import the attached FXP file using "File->Import Flex Project" menu and have a look at the code to make it much more clear.

Comment: Actually, Flash Builder can just auto-generate the MXML for you using auto-completion of the skin class.

Comment: thanks Jason. funny, I had no problem doing this w/ FB 4.0 (?) - I'll try it out and report back

Comment: I got this to work without a skin - I added backgroundAlpha=0 to the main MXML, and systemChrome and transparent attributes you've already mentioned.

Comment: Jason - with the help of a friend I solved the problem - thanks for your feedback - my explanation is below.